# How to build a basic web app on WordPress site using AWS API Gateway

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I want to build a simple Software-as-a-service web application that performs web scraping - the result per execution will be a table of results with several rows and columns. For the front-end, I wanted to build the website using WordPress since I am familiar with making basic websites there and like the plugins available. For the backend I plan on using AWS Lambda to perform the task serverless-ly. The user will log in to the site, then when they want to use the service will enter some keywords via a form, and that will send HTTP request to AWS API Gateway, which is connected to my Lambda function. Currently, the AWS Lambda function writes results into AWS DynamoDB as it goes - perhaps I need to write a second HTTP request method to query the results, or return the results in the same method that scrapes them instead.

Even after hours of googling, there are several areas in which I am unsure how to proceed, or if I have chosen the right path (I have no prior experience in this area.) Two of the biggest puzzles I have currently though are:

1. How can I use WordPress to send data to AWS API Gateway? Do I need to write some PHP code and if so what does it look like and where should I put it?
2. How can I present the results on WordPress site for the user? Should I keep the results saved on DynamoDB and query them when I want to present them, or should I store the results on the WordPress database? Ideally they would see a big table and have options to export to CSV, for example.

Thanks for your help and patience.

Cheers,
jack

Comment: You can also use elementor form o jetforms, which have better frontend options and also have webhook calls. In the other side, have u achieved to present the results from Lambda in some way? how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of possible ways this can be accomplished. One way is to just use webhooks. Most form plugins come with the option to use webhooks and doing it this way is pretty straightforward. Here is an article from WPForms on how to configure it [WPForms and Webhooks](https://wpforms.com/docs/how-to-install-and-use-the-webhooks-addon-with-wpforms/). Below is an example of how I have used it. The example shows a form that sends data to AWS API Gateway which triggers AWS StepFunctions and also puts the customer information in DynamoDB

[WPForms Webhook to AWS API Gateway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAKnW.png)

Comment: Amazing. Thank you!

Comment: So this seems like a great way to send data from Wordpress to AWS where some code can be executed and the result can be written into DynamoDB. Is it correct to say web hooks send information one-way, from WP->AWS. If I wanted to present the result of the Lambda code to a user on WP would I need to query DynamoDB separately? If so, how might I do that? :)